# How can I increased mileage of my Bike

Tags: maintenance, fuel-consumption, mileage, direct-bikes

I have a Honda CB Shine 125cc bike. When I purchased it, it was giving me mileage of 50 km/L, but now it is reduced to 40 to 45 km/L. How can I increase the mileage of my bike and increase it up to 55 km/L and above?
And what precautions needed for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some generic tips for increasing mileage:

- **clean filters:** air and fuel filters become restrictive when they get dirty. Clean them or replace them, depending on your engine's design.
- **clean fluids:** a happy engine is an efficient engine. Frequent oil changes help.
- **spark plugs:** inspect them and replace them when necessary. They set your fuel on fire, make sure they are in good shape so that they can do their job well.
- **easy on the throttle:** do not drive like the bike is on fire. Smooth is efficient.
- **easy on the revs:** Upshift early whenever you can, downshift late whenever you can.
- **mind the road and the weather:** the best advice I was ever given was "drive downhills and downwind all the time." Granted, this last bit of advice is totally impractical, but it works.

Comment: I once heard the advice "drive like there's a rotten raw egg under the accelerator and if you push it down, you'll break the shell and stink out the whole car"

Answer (score 1):

Anticipate the road more.  There is no point rushing up to a light that is red, or is likely to go red real soon.

Idling stopped is 0 km/l so avoid idling in traffic... pick times of the day where the traffic is not going to be stopped.  (assuming your location disallows lane splitting)

Contentious one, avoid engine braking.  Use the handbrakes more.  Of course this decreases fuel usage but increases brake wear.

Draughting saves energy too - but is generally too dangerous, and is only of benefit on the open road.  Round town at 50 km/h its of minimal benefit on a motorbike.

Lighten your bike saves fuel.  There's fewer places to stash crap on a bike compared to a car, but check all the storage and empty it of non-essentials.   Lightening the rider helps too.  What you need to carry is a judgement call.

Finally one of the biggies that was not yet mentioned - *Tyre pressure*  Higher pressures suffer from less rolling resistance, but give a smaller contact patch with the road and therefore less grip.  Harder tyres give more road noise and buzz too, which is no fun on chipseal roads or gravel.  Softer pressures are slightly more likely to puncture, and will sap more energy as you ride by slightly deforming the tyre.   No hard and fast advice, but try adding 5 PSI and dropping 5 PSI and compare.

Extra - good records helps.  Getting X km off one tank and X+50 off the next is a bit hard to compare if the first tank was pootling about town and the second was one single big open-road/highway trip.